# CSS select direct child items only

Tags: html, css

I have following html markup. I want to apply a css style to the `li` items which are direct children of main `ul`. I do not want to select the li items which are nested inside `li`. How can I do that?

In the following code, I want to select only "main item 1" and "main item 2". I'm trying > operator but it does not work.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a>Main item 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Main item 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a>sub item 1</a></li>
                <li><a>sub item 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.nav > ul li a:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/tk6RS/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're only selecting the parent `ul` with `>`, you'll need to add another to also pick immediate children of that `ul`, for example:

```
.nav > ul > li > a:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

You'll also need to add `li > a:hover` to select the anchor elements inside them, since the child `<a>` elements are also within the `<li>` scope.

Answer (score 4):

Just be more specific.

```
.nav > ul > li > a:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

To be more precise...

```
.nav > ul li
```

selects ANY `li` that is within the `ul` that is the direct child of `.nav`. This includes `li` that are within any submenus.

```
.nav > ul > li
```

selects only the `li` that are direct children of the `ul` that is the direct child of `.nav`.

By extension you want to only select the anchors within the selected `li` (for the same reason as above)....hence the original answer.