# target child div of ID in JavaScript and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6

I'm having difficulty targeting the child div of `id="videoContainer"` and changing its style

```
<div id="videoContainer">
  <div style="width: 640px; height: 360px">   <------- target this
    <video
      src=""
      preload="auto"
      autoplay=""
      style="width: 100%; height: 100%"
    ></video>
  </div>
</div>


const videoContainer = document.getElementById('videoContainer')
document.getElementById('videoContainer').children?.[0]?.setAttribute("style", `width: 150px; height: 200px;`);
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('#videoContainer > div')` allows you to target the child `div` directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use querySelector with [the direct child operator `>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114131/css-select-direct-child-items-only) (and maybe first with `:first-child` if you have more than one child div) like this:

```js
const videoContainer = document.querySelector('#videoContainer > div')
videoContainer.style.width =  "150px"
videoContainer.style.height = "200px"
console.log("videoContainer width is", videoContainer.style.width)
```

```css
/* what I think you need too */
#videoContainer video {
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="videoContainer">
  <div style="width: 640px; height: 360px">   <!------- target this -->
   <video src="//samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp4/sample-5s.mp4"       
    preload="auto"
    autoplay=""
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

`object-fit: contain` will force you video to scale into its parent. You may want to use `cover` or else. For more information, read [simulate `background-size:cover` on `<video>` or `<img>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40692082/1248177)

Comment: `first-child` is not required here

Comment: @Cédric in the [MRE] it is not needed, but OP mays need it in real life

Comment: Refactor, I'd like to up vote this, but you have added complexity.

Comment: Alright move `first-child` into comment

Comment: @Joseph I dont have the undefined issue in my [MRE]. Can you edit your post to add a code to showcase this problem? If it is a whole new problem, feel free to create a new question.

Comment: On reflection, I think this is a good answer. You must ensure that OP can pull out what he needs without the complexity. nice, refactor.

Comment: @MadisonCourto if you have any idea to improve the answer again, feel free to comment :)

Comment: I tried a few methods, and I think you covered it mate.

Comment: @aloisdg. weird. the `videoContainer` is null

Comment: @Joseph, I'm not getting that.

Comment: I tried console.log this `const videoContainer = document.querySelector('#videoContainer > div')` but its value is null

Comment: https://codepen.io/mcourto/pen/eYKZpzQ?editors=1111 it's 100% not null if you're doing this via dev tools, it will show null till it's called....

Comment: @aloisdg. setTimeout did the trick

Comment: @Joseph - Why are you using setTimeout?

Comment: @Yogi. probably because the video element is still being loaded?

Comment: @Joseph the video is not relevant here because we are not targeting the video. We select the container not the video. If you have a new problem, create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You can target it by adding an id/class and pointing like this in the css #Idname or .Classname
like:

file.html:

```html
<div id="videoContainer">
  <div id="idname" class="classname" style="width: 640px; height: 360px">   
    //....
  </div>
</div>
```

file.css:

```
#idname {
    width: 640px;
    height: 360px;
}
//OR
.classname {
    width: 640px;
    height: 360px;
}
```

or still with css like:

```
#videoContainer > div {
    width: 640px;
    height: 360px;
}
```

or with js:

```
const videoContainer = document.getElementById("videoContainer").firstChild; // or
const videoContainer = document.getElementById("videoContainer").childNodes[0]; //or
const videoContainer = document.querySelector('#videoContainer > div');

videoContainer.style.width = '640px';
videoContainer.style.height = '360px';
```

Comment: Welcome to SO; you're on the right track, but including the OP's original code and solution in your answer is far more beneficial to them and you in terms of acceptance.

Comment: Thank you very much, ill edit the answer to better suite the OP question

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it can be done. Hope that answers your question.

```js
document.getElementById("videoContainer").children[0].style.background="red";
```

```html
<div id="videoContainer">
  <div style="width: 640px; height: 360px">  
    <h1>Your Content </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use in this manner>>>>

document.getElementById("your_element_id").style.property = new style

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).